# How is Firebase's Realtime Database's rules working here?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The task is to make a rule that stops us from reading a user's `'height'` - but not their `'color'`.

**Database:**

```
user: {
  ryan: {
    color: "red",
    height: 170,
  },
  kirsty: {
    color: "yellow",
    height: 150,
  }
}
```

**Client code:**

```
db.ref('user/ryan/height').on('value', (e) => {
  console.log(e.val());
})
```

**Rule:**
This seems to have worked - but I don't know why. Does `height` written here capture all db values named "height"?

```
{
    "rules": { 
        ".write": true, 
        "height": {
            ".read": false 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote?  How do you know it's not working as you expect?  If you wrote client app code, please edit the question to show that.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited the question to show this. Would appreciate you having a look

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `{ "rules": { ".read": true, "$color": { ".write": false } } }`